# How to position several elements in the center with parallax.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax, parallax.js

I am trying to recreate a painting of an artist using parallax with the elements that make up the collage, but I can not understand well how to position the elements or that it is centered to the center proportionally.

I put a link to my [codepen](https://codepen.io/g3kdigital/pen/JBervx?editors=0110), because I put the code here, but I think it generates an error.

```js
var scene = document.getElementById('scene');
var parallax = new Parallax(scene, {
  relativeInput: true
});
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

:root{
  --img01: url(http://picsum.photos/1400/720/?random);
  --img02_1x: url(http://gutierrezedgar.com/parallax/img/fondo_agua-v2_@1x.jpg);
  --img02_2x: url(http://gutierrezedgar.com/parallax/img/fondo_agua-v2_@2x.jpg);
  --img03: url(http://gutierrezedgar.com/parallax/img/img_agua-v2_cuadro.png);
  --img04: url(http://gutierrezedgar.com/parallax/img/img_agua-v2_hojas.png);
  --img05: url(http://gutierrezedgar.com/parallax/img/img_agua-v2_aves.png);
  --img06: url(http://gutierrezedgar.com/parallax/img/img_agua-v2_nubes.png);
  --img07: url(http://gutierrezedgar.com/parallax/img/img_agua-v2_aves02.png);
  --img08a: url(http://gutierrezedgar.com/parallax/img/img_agua-v2_planeta01.png);
  --img08b: url(http://gutierrezedgar.com/parallax/img/img_agua-v2_planeta02.png);
  --img08c: url(http://gutierrezedgar.com/parallax/img/img_agua-v2_planeta03.png);
  --img09a: url(http://gutierrezedgar.com/parallax/img/img_agua-v2_constelacion01.png);
  --img09b: url(http://gutierrezedgar.com/parallax/img/img_agua-v2_constelacion02.png);
  --img09c: url(http://gutierrezedgar.com/parallax/img/img_agua-v2_constelacion03.png);
  --img10: url(http://gutierrezedgar.com/parallax/img/img_agua-v2_splash.png);
}

body{
  --fondo_agua: var(--img02_1x);
  --img_cuadro: var(--img03);
  --img_hojas: var(--img04);
  --img_aves: var(--img05);
  --img_aves02: var(--img07);
  --img_nubes: var(--img06);
  --img_planeta01: var(--img08a);
  --img_planeta02: var(--img08b);
  --img_planeta03: var(--img08c);
  --img_constelacion01: var(--img09a);
  --img_constelacion02: var(--img09b);
  --img_constelacion03: var(--img09c);
  --img_splash: var(--img10);
  
  background-color: #ddd;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.seccion{
  text-align: center;
}

.layer.fondo{
  margin-left: -10vw;
  margin-top: -10vw;
  width: 130vw;
  min-height: 130vh;
  background-image: var(--fondo_agua);
  background-size: cover;  
  background-position: center;
}

.layer{
  --ancho: 550px;
  --alto: 747px;
  --d: 2.6;
  --w: calc( var(--ancho) / var(--d));
  --h: calc( var(--alto) / var(--d));
  font-size: 13px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain; 
  display: inline-block; 
  width: var(--w);
  height: var(--h);  
}

.layer:not(.fondo):not(.cuadro){  
  top: calc(50% - (var(--h)/2) + (var(--y)) ) !important;
  left: calc(50% - (var(--w)/2) + (var(--x)) ) !important;
  transition: 
    width ease .3s,
    height ease .3s,
    top ease .3s,
    left ease .3s;
}

.cuadro{
  --ancho: 90vh;
  --alto: 90vh;
  --d: 1.5;
  max-width: 900px;
  max-height: 900px;
  background-image: var(--img_cuadro);
  top: calc(50% - (var(--h)/2)) !important; 
  left: calc(50% - (var(--w)/2)) !important; 
}

.hojas{
  --ancho: 550px;
  --alto: 747px;
  --x: -15em;
  --y: 0px;
  background-image: var(--img_hojas);
}

.aves{
  --ancho: 310px;
  --alto: 284px;
  --x: 6em;
  --y: -12.5em;
  background-image: var(--img_aves);
}

.aves02{
  --ancho: 315px;
  --alto: 558px;
  --x: 12em;
  --y: -6em;
  background-image: var(--img_aves02);
}

.nubes{
  --ancho: 825px;
  --alto: 322px;
  --x: 5.8em;
  --y: -12em;
  background-image: var(--img_nubes);
}

.planeta01,
.planeta02,
.planeta03{
  mix-blend-mode: screen;  
}

.planeta01{
  --ancho: 221px;
  --alto: 221px;
  --x: -12em;
  --y: 3.2em;
  background-image: var(--img_planeta01);
}

.planeta02{
  --ancho: 205px;
  --alto: 205px;
  --x: 12em;
  --y: 4em;
  background-image: var(--img_planeta02);
}

.planeta03{
  --ancho: 232px;
  --alto: 230px;
  --x: -8.5em;
  --y: -12em;
  background-image: var(--img_planeta03);
}

.const01{
  --ancho: 221px;
  --alto: 221px;
  --x: -14em;
  --y: -1em;
  background-image: var(--img_constelacion01);    
}

.const02{
  --ancho: 205px;
  --alto: 204px;
  --x: 16em;
  --y: -1.5em;
  background-image: var(--img_constelacion03);
}

.const03{
  --ancho: 232px;
  --alto: 230px;
  --x: -12.5em;
  --y: -14em;
  background-image: var(--img_constelacion02);
}

.splash{
  --ancho: 408px;
  --alto: 530px;
  --x: 1.5em;
  --y: 14em;
  background-image: var(--img_splash);
  opacity: 1;
}

@media (min-width: 600px){
  .layer{
    font-size: 16px;
    --d: 2.2;
  }
  .cuadro{
    --d: 1.2;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 960px){
  body{
    --fondo_agua: var(--img02_2x);
  }
  
  .layer{
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
  
  .cuadro{
    --ancho: 720px;
    --alto: 720px;
    --d: 1 ;
  }
  
  .hojas{
    --d: 1.6;
  }
  
  .aves02, .aves{
    --d: 1.5;
  }
  
  .aves{
    --y: -15em;
  }
  
  .splash{
    --d: 1.5;
  }

}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parallax/2.1.3/parallax.min.js"></script>


<body>
  <section class="seccion agua" id="scene">
    <figure class="layer fondo" data-depth="0.05"></figure>
    <figure class="layer cuadro" data-depth="0.20"></figure>
    <figure class="layer hojas" data-depth="0.30"></figure>
    <figure class="layer aves" data-depth="0.40"></figure>
    <figure class="layer nubes" data-depth="0.45"></figure>
    <figure class="layer aves02" data-depth="0.50"></figure>
    <figure class="layer planeta01" data-depth="0.55"></figure>
    <figure class="layer planeta02" data-depth="0.60"></figure>
    <figure class="layer planeta03" data-depth="0.55"></figure>
    <figure class="layer const01" data-depth="0.65"></figure>
    <figure class="layer const02" data-depth="0.70"></figure>
    <figure class="layer const03" data-depth="0.68"></figure>
    <figure class="layer splash" data-depth="0.80"></figure>
  </section>
</body>
```

If you notice, in some resolutions all the images are more down or up and I do not understand why.

Suddenly it's me that I'm ready with the positions using variables and units related to the viewport, but, I would like an expert to help me better understand how to place the coordinates or how to fix so that it looks more vertically .

Comment: The problem is you're using `em`s, witch are variable across DOM based on font-size of parent. If you want a single unit across all DOM use `rem`, which is root em and hence easier to set: `body{font-size: 10px !important}` I can't be sure and, considering what you've done, you are the expert on your own artwork, but I'd guess you might also have good results using `vh` as a unit, at least above a certain screen width.

Comment: Yes, I know how **em** works, which is a variable depending on the font-size of the parent element where it is declared. I use it precisely, being able to manipulate sizes quickly in a single statement in media query, but from there to whoever produces the error, I doubt it, since I first use pixels and then I make a conversion and in both cases the same thing happens. Regarding the use of **vh** I tried it for both sizes and positioning, even **vmin** but it did not solve my positioning problem, in fact I could control it more with **em**.